# How to get all entities with all ids on given list in Enity Framework ASP>NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem.
I have two tables in relation 'one' to 'many'.
I have a list that is subset of items in table on side 'many'.
I want to get elements from table on side 'one' that have relation with all elements on side 'many'.
I tried something like

```
public async Task<GetQuestionsDTO> GetQuestions(int skip, SortOptionEnum sortOption,
        List<int> tags)
    {
        IQueryable<Question> QuestionQuery = _context.Questions.AsQueryable();
        int count;
        if (tags.Count != 0)
        {
            QuestionQuery = QuestionQuery
                .Where(question => _context.QuestionTags
                    .Where(tag=>tag.IdQuestion == question.IdQuestion)
                    .Select(tag=> tag.IdTag)
                    .ToList()
                    .Intersect(tags)
                    .Equals(tags)
                );
        }
        count = await QuestionQuery.CountAsync();
        switch (sortOption)
        {
            case SortOptionEnum.Views:
                QuestionQuery = QuestionQuery.OrderBy(question => question.Views);
                break;
            case SortOptionEnum.Answers:
                QuestionQuery = QuestionQuery.OrderBy(question => question.Answers.Count);
                break;
            case SortOptionEnum.Date:
                QuestionQuery = QuestionQuery.OrderByDescending(question => question.PublishDate);
                break;
        }

        QuestionQuery = QuestionQuery.Skip(_skip).Take(_takeAmount);
        return new GetQuestionsDTO()
        {
            StandardQuestions = await QuestionQuery.Select(question => new QuestionGetQuestionsDTO()
            {
                IdQuestion = question.IdQuestion,
                AnswersCount = question.Answers.Count,
                Avatar = question.IdUserNavigation.Avatar,
                Tags = question.QuestionTags.Select(qt => qt.IdTagNavigation.Name).ToList(),
                Description = question.Description,
                Header = question.Header,
                IdUser = question.IdUser,
                IsFinished = question.IsFinished,
                IsModified = question.IsModified,
                Nickname = question.IdUserNavigation.Nickname,
                Views = question.Views,
                PublishDate = question.PublishDate
            }).ToListAsync(),
            QuestionsCount = count
        };
    }
```

but I get

``` System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List ``1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable``1[System.Int32]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable``1[System.Int32] Intersect[Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable``1[System.Int32], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[System.Int32])' (Parameter 'arg0') ```

Is there any way to do it using EntityFramework or should I use stored procedure in database?

Comment: Your query looks more complicated than I imagine it should be. To confirm….. you have questions table linked to questiontags table on a one to many. The tags array of your method are a list of tag ids that are matched to tagid on your question tag table?

Comment: Yes that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work. Questions where questiontags tagid is in the tagids array.

```
IQueryable<Question> questions = context.Questions;

foreach(int tagid in tagsid){
  
questions = questions.Where(w=> w.QuestionTags.Select(s=> s.TagId).Contains(tagid));

}
```

Building the query this way means the question must have atleast all of the tags specified in your parameter.

So essential if your parameter has id 1,2,3 the query goes. Question must have Questiontag that has 1, then Question must have questiontag containing etc

Comment: I’m on mobile so can’t confirm syntax. Also, this assumes you have navigation properties between objects.

Comment: This doesn't work :/. Isn't second where returning set of question tags? Yes, I have navigation properites between objects.

Comment: When you say doesn’t work, what does it do? The second Where doesn’t return data, you’re still getting questions. You’re just getting questions where the associated  question tags have the Ids in the array.

Comment: `I get an error:  CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.QuestionTag>' to 'bool'`  and program won't compile

Comment: I'll update: Change second where to Any. Should work

Comment: That fixed compilation issue, but not fixed problem. I want question to be returned if all of tags are in relation with question. For example when I have Question1{ tag1, tag2 } ,Question2{ tag1}, Question3 {tag1, tag2, tag3} , TagList{tag1, tag2} then I want to return only Question1 and Question3. context.Questions.Where(q=> tags.TrueForAll(tagid => context.QuestionTags.Where(qt=> qt.IdQuestion == q.IdQuestion) .Select(qt=> qt.IdTag).Any(dbtagid => dbtagid == tagid))

Comment: Sorry... That should be even easier.. Hold fire, I'll update